# Joining 2 tables using the select value from the result of a CASE

Tags: sql, t-sql, inner-join

I have 1 table where I have to show the value of 1 ID if another ID is null.

The result of that CASE I then need to use to join with a second table that has the same ID as `pid`.

I'm stuck and can't quite figure this out.  Can someone assist in helping me correct this so it works?

My query is below:

```
SELECT 
  fa.name, fa.email_address,
  CASE 
  WHEN pl.main_ID IS NULL THEN pl.sub_ID
  ELSE pl.main_ID
  END as pid ,pl.*
  FROM TableA pl 
INNER JOIN TableB fa ON fa.parent_account_sid = pl.pid
```

Comment: Tip: `coalesce(pl.main_ID, pl.sub_ID)` returns the first non-null argument.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lateral join (i.e. `apply`):

```
SELECT fa.name, fa.email_address, v.pid, pl.*
FROM TableA pl CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (COALESCE(pl.main_ID, pl.sub_ID)) v(pid) JOIN
     TableB fa
     ON fa.parent_account_sid = v.pid;
```

Of course, you might find the `COALESCE()` to be simple enough that just repeating it isn't an issue.